# Button handling and output (Wicket framework)

Tags: web, wicket, calculator

I have got a task to write a calculator on wicket and I have faced with some problems.

How to get button value(1,2,3...-,+,/,*) handle it(multiply or divide) and output a result to text field to user? Could you help me, please.

In swing it is really easy, e.g. new JtextField.setText("Shalom world!"); How I can do the same in wicket? 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use a TextField, or Label, to display the calculator value. The model for the component should get an object that you update on each click of a button. A quick way to do this would be to create a member variable in your class that holds your total and use a PropertyModel to get the value of the member variable. If you are using AjaxLink, you will need to add the TextField to your target on click of each button and you need setOutputMarkupId to be true.